# Is there any characterization of polynomials in terms of asymptotic properties of Taylor coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables

My formal question is

Let $f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ be a formal power series.

Is there any characterization of polynomials in terms of the asymptotic properties the sequence $(c_n)$?

For example, $f$ is a polynomial if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |c_n|^{1/n}=0$ and there exist $C>0$ and $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|c_n|\leq C\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |c_k|$ for all $n \geq n_0.$

Thank you very much for your help.

Masik

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The corrected version is posed.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for obfuscated versions of the simple asymptotic statement "This sequence is eventually constantly 0".

Comment: You are right. I just wonder if there is a straight-forward characterization that does not involve with $|c_n|\leq C\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |c_k|.$ I have the feeling that this should be known but I am not quite sure.

Comment: "There exists N such that $c_n = 0$ for all $n > N$" is a perfectly good asymptotic statement which characterizes polynomials and does not involve the inequality that you wish to avoid. If that statement does not answer your question, why not?